# PDF file getting corrupted for ibex Engine

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

Im using Ibex engine for PDF Generation. My PDF Document is getting corrupted 
if i set this property to my table row

```
<fo:table-row font-size="8pt" keep-together.within-column="always" >
```

Is there any specfic case where i need to use these property

Comment: When you want 8pt font and when you want the entire row to not break over a column (or page) then you want those. That does not explain your error or anything though as you have not said what "corrupted" is nor posted more than one line.

Comment: im generation pdf file to my local path using ibex engine. the file size is growing drastically. and i could not able to open the file if i set keep-together.within-column="always". if i remove the keep-together.within-column="always"  property i able to  generate my file.

Comment: How much content is inside the table-row? Are you formatting a single table row that is many, many pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keep-together.within-column="always"` is a potential source of trouble. If your table row becomes longer than the page, the formatter will still try to render the row on one page, potentially writing over the page footer and off the page. Try setting it to a numerical value instead:
`keep-together.within-column="100"`

Comment: You can click the check mark to accept my answer, that way the site knows the question isn't still unanswered.